# Using Bayer's Formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a student council comprised of 1 girl and 2 boys. It will be expanded to include 2 new members. There are 4 girls and 6 boys that can go in. So there will be 5 members, 3 old, 2 new.

What is the probability that we pick a girl from the newly selected board? I was trying to think about this problem and figure out how to go about it, but I was thinking, it is the probability of getting a girl given she is from the original three times the probability that the other two spots are both girls or something? I am quite sure Bayer's formula should be used, but there is nothing given I guess.

Secondly, A proposal is under review by the expanded union. The chance of supporting the proposal is 80% from a boy and 40% from a girl. What is the chance that is supported by everyone?

In order to solve this problem, I was thinking $P(E)=P(G)+P(B)-P(GB)$ in terms of who supports it. but how do I go about finding each of these with the expanded union?

Comment: Mr. Bayer was a high school math teacher I had. The law of probability is named after Rev. Thomas Bayes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of picking $2$ girls as the new members is:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{4+6}{2}}=\frac{2}{15}$$

The probability of picking $2$ boys as the new members is:

$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{4+6}{2}}=\frac{5}{15}$$

The probability of picking $1$ girl and $1$ boy as the new members is:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{4+6}{2}}=\frac{8}{15}$$

---

Therefore:

- The probability of a new council with $3$ girls and $2$ boys is $\frac{2}{15}$
- The probability of a new council with $1$ girl  and $4$ boys is $\frac{5}{15}$
- The probability of a new council with $2$ girls and $3$ boys is $\frac{8}{15}$

---

Hence the probability of picking a girl from the new council is:

$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}\cdot\frac{2}{15}+\frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}\cdot\frac{5}{15}+\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}\cdot\frac{8}{15}=\frac{9}{25}=36\%$$

And the probability that the proposal is supported by everyone is:

$$0.4^3\cdot0.8^2\cdot\frac{2}{15}+0.4^1\cdot0.8^4\cdot\frac{5}{15}+0.4^2\cdot0.8^3\cdot\frac{8}{15}\approx10.37\%$$